# Video selection using <select> tag does not work

Tags: javascript, video

I am implementing a video selection functionality to my video play so that people can choose which video they would like to watch. My current code goes like this:

html:

```
<video id="media" width="600" height="400" preload="none">
       <source id="myvideos" src="files/Best of 60s.m4v"> </source>
</video>
<select id="videos">
        <option value="PleaseSelect" selected="selected">Please Select...</option>
        <option value="files/Best of 60s.m4v">Best of 60s</option>
        <option value="files/Black and White Gems.m4v">Black and White Gems</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
var selectmenu, mmedia;
selectmenu=document.getElementById('videos'); 
mmedia = document.getElementById('media');

selectmenu.addEventListener('onchange', loadvid);

function loadvid(){
selectmenu.onchange=function(){
    var chosenoption=this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    if (chosenoption.value != "PleaseSelect"){
        mmedia.src = chosenoption.value;
    }
    mmedia.load();  
  }
}
```

When I run this code no "link" gets created between what I choose in the select menu to what plays except for what I have stated in the src element.

I implemented this with the following mindset:

To have an onchange event attached to the select element so the  function loadvid() only fires off when something changes in the menu.

The loadvid function than manages the choice of video by defining the value of the selected index and passing it to mmedia; which is a video element and has the src property.

Once the selection is made the video then should load (mmedia.load()).

I have obviously gone wrong somewhere and would appreciate any guidance you can provide.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript has an "onchange" where "change" is needed; in addition extraneous function is commented out below:

```
var selectmenu, mmedia;
selectmenu = document.getElementById('videos');
mmedia = document.getElementById('media');

selectmenu.addEventListener('change', loadvid);

function loadvid() {
    //selectmenu.onchange=function(){
    var chosenoption = this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    if (chosenoption.value != "PleaseSelect") {
        alert(chosenoption.value);
        mmedia.src = chosenoption.value;
    }
    mmedia.load();
    // }
}
```

The other problem you're going to encounter is using `<source>` in your   `<video>` tag; you might have less trouble if you simply use a `src=` attribute in the video tag:

```
<video name="media" id="media" width="600" height="400" preload="none" src="files/Best of 60s.m4v"></video>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, however, there is a "typo" preventing your code from working:

In your `addEventListener` call, you tell it to listen for `onchange` which isn't an actual event. MDN has a handy [list of events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events). You'll want to use the [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change) event instead.

*The `on` prefix is used when you add a listener directly as a HTML attribute like so `<select onchange="loadvid()">`*.

**Side-note:** Since you've already attached an event listener here:

```
selectmenu.addEventListener('change', loadvid);
```

...You don't need to do it again here:

```
function loadvid(){
selectmenu.onchange=function(){
```

Take care of those 2 and you get this working code:

```
var selectmenu, mmedia;
selectmenu = document.getElementById('videos'); 
mmedia = document.getElementById('media');

selectmenu.addEventListener('change', loadvid);

function loadvid(){
    var chosenoption=this.options[this.selectedIndex];
    console.log(chosenoption);
    if (chosenoption.value != "PleaseSelect"){
        mmedia.src = chosenoption.value;
    }
    mmedia.load();  
}
```

Comment: Hi Lasse Ott Kartin, many thanks for the explanation and pointing this out.